# In SQL how to populate lowest value from the list

Tags: sql

[image]

[image]

From below table if an Asbesto Survey id have multiple ASbestos Status Lines then i need to populate the lowest value as Asbestos Status on line Level like below.

I have used left join and case statement but its not working.

Comment: Questions: Do you have a lookup table that defines the asbestos status ranking? Do you need values like "UPRN" in the output? Can you post the SQL you've tried?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

**Left join** and a **window function** will help you solve your problem.

Consider below query which assuming **sample** and **rank** are tables in your screenshot respectively.

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       LAST_VALUE(Asbestos_Status) OVER (
         PARTITION BY UPRN, Asbesto_survey_id ORDER BY rank RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
       ) AS Asbestos_Status_on_line_level
  FROM sample s LEFT JOIN rank r ON s.Asbesto_status_lines = r.Asbestos_Status
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer which is very precise and i will give try. I got alternate solution which is working

Answer (score 0):

I have assigned ranking to each status inner joined with main table Lines table and fetch the max rank

```
SELECT [Asbestos Survey ID],MAX(RANKING) AS ASBESTOS_STATUS_RANK
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT [Asbestos Survey ID],AsbestosStatus,x.RANKING
from table1 a -- above first table.
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT 'Removed' AS AsbestosStatus, 6 AS RANKING
                UNION
                SELECT 'No Asbestos Detected' AS AsbestosStatus, 5 AS RANKING
                UNION
                SELECT 'Presumed No Access' AS AsbestosStatus, 4 AS RANKING
                UNION
                SELECT 'Presumed'  AS AsbestosStatus, 3 AS RANKING
                UNION
                SELECT 'Strongly Presumed' AS AsbestosStatus, 2 AS RANKING
                UNION
                SELECT 'Confirmed' AS AsbestosStatus, 1 AS RANKING
                ) X ON X.AsbestosStatus = A.AsbestosStatus
) Y
GROUP BY SURVEYID
```

So above i would get SurveyID and Max rank on the survey id and i will populate that max survey id based on Table 2.